# Am I the only one who this has been happening to?

Tags: sentence-structure, prepositional-phrases, relative-pronouns, pied-piping

Which one is correct, I got confused:

- Am I the only one who this has been happening to?
- Am I the only one to who this has been happening to?
- Am I the only one to who this has been happening?

Comment: The most idiomatic forms are _Am I the only one_ [ _that_ ] _this has been happening to?_

Comment: The best answer is "Am I the only one this has been happening to?" Under no circumstances should you use the pied-piping "to who(m)" silliness, as it is profoundly unnatural in speech.

Answer (score -1):

You can also say, "Does this only happen to me?"

From your options the third one is the best choice. Very few people in America still use the word "whom" when speaking, I sometimes use it when I want to sound like a pretentious douchebag. But you should know that in formal writing you're supposed to use "whom" when the word preceding it is a preposition (i.e. to, from, about, of, etc.).

Here is a very useful link from Washington State University regarding [who/whom](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/who-whom/).

Answer (score -3):

None of those.

The correct variants are:
'Am I the only one whom this has been happening to?'
'Am I the only one to whom this has been happening?'

Comment: There is nothing "grammatically incorrect" about either of these, but an entire generation of native speakers was so traumatized by their English teachers' ham-handed teaching of this useful objective pronoun that a retaliatory campaign to erase it from memory has been in progress for decades. You are advised to use it only when you are in no danger of being thought a "pretentious douchebag" by those who find it threatening or confusing. Do not, for instance, use it at the ballgame by yelling: _"Whom are you calling out, ump?"_